# init script terminating with ssh session

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, init.d

We need to run [pt-stalk](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-stalk.html) on a handful of servers to keep an eye on mySQL, and I was sick of manually starting it every time the server rebooted. A little googling turned up an [init script](https://github.com/9minutesnooze/pt-init-scripts/blob/master/etc/init.d/pt-stalk) for pt-stalk, and it seemed to work just fine. [my slightly modified version included at the bottom of this post]

It was taking too long to figure out how to push the script and config out via ssh [long story, please don't ask] so I decided to just log into the 20-odd servers and set everything up manually and everything worked.

A couple days later my coworker commented that he was getting the emails, but I clearly wasn't, and it looked like I had put the wrong email in the config. This time I had figured out how to push the change via ssh, and finished everything off with:

```
for server in `cat serverlist.txt`; do
  ssh -t $server sudo -i service pt-stalk restart
done
```

And this is the point where pt-stalk stopped working on every single server with:

```
2013_08_23_11_43_20 Caught signal, exiting
2013_08_23_11_43_20 Exiting because OKTORUN is false
2013_08_23_11_43_20 /usr/bin/pt-stalk exit status 1
2013_08_23_11_43_22 Starting /usr/bin/pt-stalk --function=status --variable=Threads_connected --threshold=100 --match= --cycles=5 --interval=1 --iterations= --run-time=30 --sleep=300 --dest=/var/lib/pt-stalk --prefix= --notify-by-email=servers@domain.com --log=/var/log/pt-stalk.log --pid=/var/run/pt-stalk.pid
2013_08_23_11_43_22 Caught signal, exiting
```

Through yesterday's testing I've deciphered that 'Caught signal, exiting' means it's caught a `HUP`/`TERM`/`KILL`. The first one is from `service pt-stalk restart`, and the *second* one immediately after the *successful* start is from when the ssh session closes. wat.jpg

If I simply ssh to the server, enter `sudo -i service pt-stalk start` or `restart` I can log out and it continues happily. However, if I just feed a command to ssh like the above loop pt-stalk it catches a signal and exits. Sometimes it catches *two* signals before it exits.

What the hell is going on?

---

My /etc/init.d/pt-stalk for reference:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# chkconfig: 2345 20 80
# description: pt-stalk
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: pt-stalk
# Required-Start: $network $named $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop: $network $named $remote_fs $syslog
# Should-Start: pt-stalk
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON="/usr/bin/pt-stalk"
DAEMON_OPTS="--config /etc/pt-stalk.conf"
NAME="pt-stalk"
DESC="pt-stalk"
PIDFILE="/var/run/${NAME}.pid"
STALKHOME="/var/lib/pt-stalk"

test -x $DAEMON || exit 1

[ -r /etc/default/pt-stalk ] && . /etc/default/pt-stalk

#. /lib/lsb/init-functions

sig () {
    test -s "$PIDFILE" && kill -$1 `cat $PIDFILE`
}

start() {
  if [[ -z $MYSQL_OPTS ]]; then
HOME=$STALKHOME $DAEMON $DAEMON_OPTS
  else
HOME=$STALKHOME $DAEMON $DAEMON_OPTS -- $MYSQL_OPTS
  fi
return $?
}

stop() {
  if sig TERM; then
    while sig 0 ; do
      echo -n "."
      sleep 1
    done
    return 0
  else
    echo "$DESC is not running."
    return 1
  fi
}

status() {
  if sig 0 ; then
    echo "$DESC (`cat $PIDFILE`) is running."
    return 0
  else
    echo "$DESC is stopped."
    return 1
  fi
}

log_begin_msg() {
        echo $1
}

log_end_msg() {
        if [ $1 -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "Success"
        else
                echo "Failure"
        fi
}

case "$1" in
  start)
   log_begin_msg "Starting $DESC"
   start
   log_end_msg $?
   ;;

  stop)
   log_begin_msg "Stopping $DESC"
   stop
   log_end_msg $?
   ;;
  status)
    status ;;

  restart)
    log_begin_msg "Restarting $DESC"
    stop
    sleep 1
    start
    log_end_msg $?
    ;;

  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|}" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: You should really be looking at puppet/chef/configuration management tools.  Managing servers via an ssh for loop should be avoided.

Comment: Why are you using the `-i` option to `sudo`?

Comment: @MichaelHampton So that the command is invoked after reading in the relevant .profile/.bash_profile/etcetera for the root user.

Comment: Can you try and modify your sudoers config and comment out "Default requiretty"?

Comment: @DanilaLadner that's done it, but I don't get why every other init script/daemon/service works fine except for this one

Comment: Can you restart mysqld without tty through ssh -t with sudo when tty for sudo is required?

Answer (score 0):

Since your daemon is terminated at once I'm pretty sure that if the `--daemonize` option is given to `/usr/bin/pt-stalk` it might not close one of the file descriptors `stdin`, `stdout` or `stderr` properly and early enough 
or/and does not handle the `SIGHUP` signal correctly.

To test which of my assumptions is correct, modify your `init` script so that input and output of `start` are redirected from and to `/dev/null`.  Example:

```
start </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

If this removes the early termination problem narrow it down by removing these redirections one after the other again.  It might be that `pt-stalk` simply forks **to early**.  In this case inserting another `sleep 1` after the call to `start` might also be able to work around this.  If it comes out to the handling of the `SIGHUP` signal then it might also be a workaround to modify your `init` script by adding this:

```
trap "echo SIGHUP ignored" 1
```

before the call to `start` and this:

```
trap - 1
```

right after the call to `start`.

I did not download `pt-stalk` and had no look into it and did not test my theory described above.  This was all from my experiences with other daemons.